# On a special vector field on Riemannian Manifolds?

Tags: proof-verification, differential-geometry

Suppose that $(M,g)$ is a Riemannain manifold $dV_g$ is its volume element and $X$ is a non-zero smooth vector field on $M$. If for every 1-form $\delta$ we have the following equality,
$$\int_M \delta (X) dV_g=0.$$

> What is the most important result can we deduce about $X$?

I tried with
$$0=\int_M \delta (X) dV_g=\int_M <i_X g,\delta> dV_g$$
and these equalities hold for any $\delta$ if $X=0$. But the assumption specifies that $X\neq 0$. So I think the condition of problem never happens.

Comment: This means $X$ has to be the zero vector field.

Comment: Thank you.According to the assumption the vector field is non-zero.

Comment: I think, ........